# visionOS Portal doesn't attach to a wall when a wall AnchorEntity exists

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

I saw this post on having trouble anchoring a portal to a wall:
[visionOS Portal not show when is child of AnchorEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77888105/visionos-portal-not-show-when-is-child-of-anchorentity)

But I wasn't able to fix the issue, even after doing what seemed like the correct solution.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct PortalView : View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let anchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.vertical,
                              classification: .wall,
                               minimumBounds: [1, 1]))

            let world = makeWorld()
            let portal = makePortal(world: world)
            
            anchor.addChild(portal)
            content.add(world)
            content.add(anchor)
            let _ = content.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.AnchoredStateChanged.self,
                                                  on: anchor) { event in
                            print("Anchored State Changed")
                        }
        }
    }

    @MainActor func makeWorld() -> Entity {
        let world = Entity()
        world.components[WorldComponent.self] = .init()

        let environment = try! EnvironmentResource.load(named: "Sunlight")
        world.components[ImageBasedLightComponent.self] = .init(source: .single(environment), intensityExponent: 12)
        world.components[ImageBasedLightReceiverComponent.self] = .init(imageBasedLight: world)

        let earth = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "Earth", in: realityKitContentBundle)
        earth.position = SIMD3<Float>(x: -0.1, y: 0, z: -0.4)
        world.addChild(earth)

        return world
    }

    @MainActor func makePortal(world: Entity) -> Entity {
        let portal = Entity()

        
        portal.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: -.pi/2, axis: [1,0,0]) // rotate CW

        portal.components[ModelComponent.self] = .init(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 1,
                                                                            height: 1,
                                                                            cornerRadius: 0.5),
                                                       materials: [PortalMaterial()])
        portal.components[PortalComponent.self] = .init(target: world)

        return portal
    }
}

#Preview {
    PortalView()
}
```

When I change the first function code to this:

```
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let anchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.vertical,
                              classification: .wall,
                               minimumBounds: [1, 1]))

            let world = makeWorld()
            let portal = makePortal(world: world)
            
            //anchor.addChild(portal)
            content.add(world)
            content.add(portal)
            let _ = content.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.AnchoredStateChanged.self,
                                                  on: anchor) { event in
                            print("Anchored State Changed")
                        }
        }
    }
```

Then I am able to see a portal on screen, but not anchored to a wall. [image]

Here's my section calling the code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct <AppName>: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            PortalView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I needed this in my main file:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Day9App: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        ImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace") {
            PortalView()
        }
    }
}
```

And then this line in my project settings:
Preferred Default Scene Session Role:Immersive Space Application Session Role